# How add item to TableView from file with loop

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, fxml

I use this class to add items to tableview javafx but it just add the last line of file to tableview.
 I use ObservableList in this class
  how can I solve this problem?

```
public class MyTicket {
String name;
@FXML
private Button back;    
@FXML
private TableView<ShowTicket> table;     
@FXML
private TableColumn<ShowTicket, String> origin; 
@FXML
private TableColumn<ShowTicket, String> goal;    
@FXML
private TableColumn<ShowTicket, String> date;    
public void addName(String userName){
    name= userName;
}   
public void adddata(){      
    String originFile= name + "\\" +name + "origin" + ".txt";   
    String goalFile= name + "\\" +name + "goal" + ".txt";
    String dateFile= name + "\\" +name + "date" + ".txt";       
        try {           
            BufferedReader inputOrigin= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(originFile));
            BufferedReader inputGoal= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(goalFile));
            BufferedReader inputDate= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dateFile));
            String line1= inputOrigin.readLine();
            String line2= inputGoal.readLine();
            String line3= inputDate.readLine();
            ArrayList<String> or= new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> go= new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> da= new ArrayList<>();
            while(line1 != null){                   
                or.add(line1);
                go.add(line2);
                da.add(line3);                  
                line1= inputOrigin.readLine();
                line2= inputGoal.readLine();
                line3= inputDate.readLine();
            }
            int i= or.size();               
            for(int j=0; j<i; j++){                 
                ObservableList<ShowTicket> contactList= FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                        new ShowTicket(or.get(j), go.get(j), da.get(j)));
                table.setItems(contactList);
                origin.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("firstName"));
                goal.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("lastName"));
                date.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("cellPhone"));
            }                               
                inputOrigin.close();
                inputGoal.close();
                inputDate.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e){                
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}//adddata
```

my ShowTicket class:

http://textuploader.com/d0a3e

Answer (score 0):

> I use this class to add items to tableview javafx but it just add the
>   last line of file to tableview.

It is expected as you overwrite the value of the property `items` of the `TableView` object at each iteration :

```
for(int j=0; j<i; j++){                 
    ...
   ObservableList<ShowTicket> contactList= FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                        new ShowTicket(or.get(j), go.get(j), da.get(j)));
   table.setItems(contactList);
   ...
}
```

You should rather create an `contactList` object that contains the `ShowTicket` of all the lines.

```
ObservableList<ShowTicket> contactList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
for(int j=0; j<i; j++){                         ...
   contactList.addAll(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                        new ShowTicket(or.get(j), go.get(j), da.get(j)));       
}
```

Then you could invoke `table.setItems(contactList);`.

Comment: Sadly, this answer causes `ObservableList<ShowTicket> cannot be converted to ObservableList<CAP#1>`